# Обход полей формы с использованием jQuery

Tags: javascript, jquery

Сверстал форму:

```
<form name="mainForm" method="get" id="mainForm">
  <div class="row">
    <div class="col-xs-6 col-md-4">
      <div class="block-1">
        <!--First name-->
        <div class="form-group">
          <input type="text" class="form-control" id="firstName" name="firstName" placeholder="First Name" value="">
          <label for="firstName" id="firstNameLabel" style="color: transparent">"Field must be filled out"</label>
        </div>
        <!--Last name-->
        <div class="form-group">
          <input type="text" class="form-control" id="lastName" name="lastName" placeholder="Last Name">
          <label for="LastName" id="lastNameLabel" style="color: transparent">"Field must be filled out"</label>
        </div>
        <!--Title-->
        <div class="form-group">
          <span class="input-group-btn">
            <select id="titles" class="selectpicker form-control"
                data-live-search="true" name="titleName" title="Please select a lunch ...">
              <option selected></option>
              <option>Mr.</option>
              <option>Ms.</option>
            </select>
          </span>
          <label for="titles" id="titlesLabel" style="color: transparent">"Field must be filled out"</label>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</form>
<!--Button-->
<div class="row">
  <div class="col-md-3 col-offset-9">
    <input type="button" onclick="return jqvalidation()" name="data" id="submitButton" class="btn btn-large btn-danger form-control" value="Send">
    </input>
  </div>
</div>
```

И написал функцию для валидации полей формы с использованием jQuery, но она ещё не закончена:

```
function jqvalidation() {
    var elems = $('.block-1');
    var f = 0;
    jQuery.each(elems, function (key, val) {
        if ($(val).val() == "" || $(val).val() == null) {
            $(val).css('border', '1px solid red');
            $(val).attr("placeholder", "Field must be filled out").addClass('error');
            f = 1;
        }
        else {
            $(val).css('border', '#ccc');
        }
    });
    if (f == 1) {
        return false;
    }
}
```

Как правильно обращаться к элементам `<input>` и `<label>`, вложенным в элементы с классом `block-1`?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Получение всех `<input>` и `<label>` внутри элементов с классом `block-1`:

```
var $elements = $('.block-1').find('input,label');
```

Получение всех `<input>` и `<label>` отдельно для каждого элемента с классом `block-1`:

```
$('.block-1').each(function() {
    var $elements = $(this).find('input,label'); //this указывает на текущий элемент с классом block-1
});
```

Получение всех `<input>` и `<select>` внутри элементов с классом `block-1` и обработка каждого из них по отдельности:

```
$('.block-1').find('input,select').each(function() {
    var $this = $(this); //this указывает на текущий input или select
    if ($this.val() == "") {
        ...
    }
    ...
});
```

Что касается модификации вашего кода:

1. Элемент с классом `block-1` всего один, поэтому нет смысла делать по нему `.each()`. Имеет смысл делать `.each()` по всем `<input>`-ам внутри него.
2. Использование `<label>`-ов в вашем коде я не увидел, поэтому в переделанной версии они не фигурируют.
3. `.val()`, `.css()`, `.attr()` и `.addClass()` нужно применять к самому `<input>`-у, а не к блоку, его содержащему.
4. Переменная с ничего не значащим именем `f` переименована в `hasError`, также хранимые в ней данные с `Number` (`0` и `1`) заменены на `Boolean` (`false` и `true`). Нет смысла хранить "да/нет" в виде числа. Так как `return` не несёт никакой пользы в данном коде, то весь код, связанный с `hasError` и `return`, закомментирован.
5. Использование inline JS (`onclick=""`) считает плохим тоном. Вызов функции заменён на `$('#submitButton').on("click", function() {`.

Итоговая версия:

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
  $('#submitButton').on("click", function() {
    //var hasError = false;
    $('.block-1 input').each(function() {
      var $this = $(this);
      if ($this.val() == "") {
        $this.css('border', '1px solid red');
        $this.attr("placeholder", "Field must be filled out");
        $this.addClass('error');
        //hasError = true;
      } else {
        $this.css('border', '#ccc');
      }
    });
    //return hasError;
  });
});
```

```html
<form name="mainForm" method="get" id="mainForm">
  <div class="row">
    <div class="col-xs-6 col-md-4">
      <div class="block-1">
        <!--First name-->
        <div class="form-group">
          <input type="text" class="form-control" id="firstName" name="firstName" placeholder="First Name" value="">
          <label for="firstName" id="firstNameLabel" style="color: transparent">"Field must be filled out"</label>
        </div>
        <!--Last name-->
        <div class="form-group">
          <input type="text" class="form-control" id="lastName" name="lastName" placeholder="Last Name">
          <label for="LastName" id="lastNameLabel" style="color: transparent">"Field must be filled out"</label>
        </div>
        <!--Title-->
        <div class="form-group">
          <span class="input-group-btn">
            <select id="titles" class="selectpicker form-control"
                data-live-search="true" name="titleName" title="Please select a lunch ...">
              <option selected></option>
              <option>Mr.</option>
              <option>Ms.</option>
            </select>
          </span>
          <label for="titles" id="titlesLabel" style="color: transparent">"Field must be filled out"</label>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</form>
<!--Button-->
<div class="row">
  <div class="col-md-3 col-offset-9">
    <input type="button" name="data" id="submitButton" class="btn btn-large btn-danger form-control" value="Send">
  </div>
</div>

<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
```

Какие проблемы я вижу в этой версии:

1. По клику на `#submitButton` не происходит отправка формы. Имеет смысл переделать на один из этих вариантов:

   - внести эту кнопку в форму, сменив её `type` на `submit`, и добавить обработчик (со всеми этими проверками) события `submit` на саму форму.
   - делать в обработчике отправку формы в случае успешного прохождения валидации:

     ```
     if (!hasError) {
         $('#mainForm').submit();
     }
     ```
   - отправлять в обработчике форму с помощью Ajax (опять-таки в случае успешного прохождения валидации).
2. Отсутствует проверка значения в `<select "id="titles">`.
3. Сообщение о незаполненном (и неправильно заполненном) поле не стоит делать в виде `placeholder`-a. В случае незаполненной поля оно просто заменяет подсказку о том, что должно быть в этом поле, а в случае неправильно заполненного поля его будет попросту не видно. Можно либо использовать для этого уже созданные (видимо, с этой же целью) `<label>`-ы, либо создать какие-то отдельные элементы для этого.

Версия, исправляющая эти проблемы:

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
  $('#submitButton').on("click", function() {
    var hasError = false;
    $('.form-group').each(function() {
      var $this = $(this);
      var $input = $this.find('input,select');
      var $error = $this.find('.errorMessage');
      if ($input.val() == "") {
        $input.addClass("errorField");
        $error.show();
        hasError = true;
      } else {
        $input.removeClass("errorField");
        $error.hide();
      }
    });
    if (!hasError) {
     $('#mainForm').submit();
    }
  });
});
```

```css
.errorField {
  border: 1px solid red;
}

.errorMessage {
  color: red;
  display: none;
}
```

```html
<form name="mainForm" method="get" id="mainForm" action="">
  <div class="row">
    <div class="col-xs-6 col-md-4">
      <div class="block-1">
        <!--First name-->
        <div class="form-group">
          <input type="text" class="form-control" id="firstName" name="firstName" placeholder="First Name" value="">
          <label for="firstName" id="firstNameLabel" class="errorMessage">"Field must be filled out"</label>
        </div>
        <!--Last name-->
        <div class="form-group">
          <input type="text" class="form-control" id="lastName" name="lastName" placeholder="Last Name">
          <label for="LastName" id="lastNameLabel" class="errorMessage">"Field must be filled out"</label>
        </div>
        <!--Title-->
        <div class="form-group">
          <span class="input-group-btn">
            <select id="titles" class="selectpicker form-control"
                data-live-search="true" name="titleName" title="Please select a lunch ...">
              <option selected></option>
              <option>Mr.</option>
              <option>Ms.</option>
            </select>
          </span>
          <label for="titles" id="titlesLabel" class="errorMessage">"Field must be filled out"</label>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</form>
<!--Button-->
<div class="row">
  <div class="col-md-3 col-offset-9">
    <input type="button" name="data" id="submitButton" class="btn btn-large btn-danger form-control" value="Send">
  </div>
</div>

<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
```

В этой версии предполагается, что все поля для валидации находятся в блоках `.form-group`, и каждый блок `.form-group` содержит ровно один `<input>` или `<select>`.

Comment: здесь ошибка: `$('.block-1 input,label');` внутри _.block-1_ будут искаться только _input_, _label_ же будет выбираться по всей странице

Comment: @Grundy каюсь, согрешил.

Comment: как вариант можно было `$('.block-1 input, .block-1 label')`

Comment: и с select что-от не работает

Comment: @Grundy а его в исходном коде и в заданном вопросе попросту нет. В проблемах итоговой версии я это упомянул. Думаю, стоит сделать ещё одну версию, исправляющую эти ошибки.

Comment: вообще в начальном варианте в посте - проход делается вообще по всем элементам, не выбирая _input_, _select_. Из разметки в посте: _select id="titles"_

Comment: @Grundy в коде в вопросе вообще `$('.block-1').each()`, что чуть больше, чем просто странно. И потому, что элемент такой один, и потому, что обход нужен по `input` и `select`.

Comment: Давайте [продолжим обсуждение в чате](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/32417/discussion-between-grundy-and-regent).

Comment: Всем большое спасибо!Понял свои ошибки